# Determine when the app becomes active from minimized to foreground - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume, onpause

I am trying to trigger an unlock screen when the app goes from the background to the foreground.

All my activities are extending a base class which overrides onPause + onResume.

The **problem** with **onPause** is that this method gets called even when you launch a new intent.

What is a reliable way of determining when an app becomes **active**?

Regards,

Tim

Answer (score -1):

Looks like `onResume()` will do the job for you. As for the case of extending from a base class, do not forget to call `super.onResume()` so your `onResume` will end up looking like this :

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    // your stuff
}
```

Comment: Strictly relying on onResume will not work.   There needs to be an off + on state from being minimized.  onResume gets called on intent creation:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html